# C : Dynamic spacing when printing values

Tags: c, printing, printf, column-width, pascals-triangle

I'm doing a homework assignment in C where part of it involves printing the values with certain spacing between each integer. For example, using Pascal's Triangle:

```
  1 
  1 1 
  1 2  1 
  1 3  3  1 
  1 4  6  4   1 
  1 5 10 10   5   1 
  1 6 15 20  15   6  1 
  1 7 21 35  35  21  7  1 
  1 8 28 56  70  56 28  8 1 
  1 9 36 84 126 126 84 36 9 1
```

The spacing between the integers in each column is exactly as wide as the largest integer +1. What's the best way to approach this?

Comment: Have you read through the documentation for `printf()`?

Comment: yes. I already know about the asterisk

Comment: Well there you go then. Figure out the maximum length needed for each column and use that when printing the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic spacing using `printf` can be achieved using the special character `*`.

> A field width, or precision, or both, may be indicated by an asterisk. In this case, an int argument supplies the field width or precision.

Here is a basic testing program. You may want to use the special character `-`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;

    printf("Select your spacing: ");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    printf("Spacing is at least %d: |%*d|\n", i, i, 1);
    printf("Spacing is at least %d: |%-*d|\n", i, i, 1);
    return (0);
}
```

You still need to find the largest number from your problem and to process its width. This has to be done before you print anything. Good luck !